# Why can't groovy deal with curly braces?

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, indentation, curly-braces

In an Android Studio (and presumably ANY) gradle file, the following code works:

```
task build {
}
```

And one minor change causes a complete meltdown:

```
task build
{
}
```

This has come up in other threads before, but in the context of fixing the build files. My question is why can't gradle/groovy be made to deal with either bracing style? Many other languages cope just fine with it, so what's the big deal here?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually all right there in the error message:

```
build file '.../build.gradle': 80: Ambiguous expression could be a parameterless closure expression, an isolated open code block, or it may continue a previous statement;
     solution: Add an explicit parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}, and also either remove the previous newline, or add an explicit semicolon ';' @ line 80, column 1.
```

Because of a Groovy syntax sugar to make methods with a lambda as the last parameter look line language constructs, the following code blocks:

```
task build {}
task build2(type: Copy) {}
```

are equal to their more regular form:

```
task build({})
task build(type: Copy, {})
```

Now, you do not really want those curly braces there to delimit a regular code block, but a Groovy lambda, which should be passed as a parameter to the `build` method.

Yet from the looks of it, Groovy can't really decide if it really is a lambda being passed as a parameter to the method in the previous line or an unrelated code block when you put a newline in between. And there you go, an ambiguousness as described in the error message, right there.

Following the advice in the error message, you can also use the following syntax instead of the one where you are escaping the new-line character:

```
task build
{ -> 
}
```

Finally, the `task` keyword used to invoke the dynamic method (named `build` in your example) is not Groovy specific, but a Gradle DSL feature.

Comment: but `doLast \n{ ...` works...  Think it's more of a DSL issue when parsing task definition

Comment: Interesting... The error and why it happens looked pure Groovy to me, see method at line 2122 (whatever happened to short classes, ha!) and related groovydoc: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g . 

Could it be because doLast is a statically defined (not `static`, of course) method which always requires a single closure parameter ( https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html ) and the methods invoked following the `task` keyword in gradle are all dynamic so there is no way to tell what parameters should they have?

Comment: It's definitely a 'build' task DSL issue/implementation choice, because none of the other 'keywords' I use have this problem (buildscript, plugins, release, artifactory, etc.).

Comment: Yes. `buildscript`, `plugins` etc. are all invocations of statically defined methods accepting a single `Closure` type parameter. Knowing that the invocation is not complete without the parameter, there is no ambiguousness. `task` is somewhat special because it has an `Action` parameter, which is created by invoking a dynamic method (here it is `build` but the name is completely arbitrary and makes no difference), whose exact parameter list is not defined, hence ambiguousness. The way the dynamic method invocation is coerced to an `Action` instance is a Gradle DSL intricacy.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone reading this is wondering, the work-around is simple enough.

```
task build \
{
}
```

I was just wondering as to the "why"...

Comment: gradle build scripts are a DSL, not strictly a groovy script or class file.  I feel this is a bug however, it might be worth posting it as an [issue on the issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues)?